# Rendering problems using new TextInputLayout for EditText

Tags: android

I'm trying to set the new support.desing library that provides some lollipop visual effects to old android versions.

In this case, I'm triying to add the floating labels for the edittext, which is done with the widget.TextInputLayout:

[image]

To do this I have followed google's provided few indications:

- I have downloaded the last support library (22.2.0) and included on graddle file.

  compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
- I have added the TextInputLayout in my xml this way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="12"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/edt" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

But Android Studio is showing this in the layout preview:

```
Rendering failed with a known bug. Please try a rebuild.  
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Exception Details 
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TextAppearance
```

This is the style I'm using:

```
<style name="MaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_red_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/md_green_500</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/md_grey_900</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/md_grey_600</item>
</style>
```

EDIT-

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved. Had to add this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
```

Where this just is:

```
<style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
```