# The following classes could not be instantiated: android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

Trying to learn Android development. I am using Android Studio 2.1.3 and tried to create a login feature. Made use of Login Activity template while creating the project and left everything else in the wizard to be default. When I tried to preview what exactly it has created it shows this error.

The following classes could not be instantiated: android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

By default the android version to target was showing as 24 I changed it to 15 but still the same error. How to solve this?

[image]

**Layout xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.user.loginapp.Login">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the XML for the layout file you are using?

Comment: Also, try the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575815/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-too and see if one of them works for you.

Comment: @ChadSchultz I have updated the question with layout xml now. Also I have tried to Invalidate Caches / Restart it didn't solve the problem. Also I tried changing the android version from 24 to 15 it too didn't solve the problem

Comment: The good news: the problem happens for me too! It's not just your.
The bad news: I haven't found a way to fix it. There are a number of discussions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570569/rendering-problems-using-new-textinputlayout-for-edittext
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575815/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-too
and more, but none worked for me.
The visual editor is just super buggy. Hope Google fixes it someday! This is why I always just test layouts on the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use appcompat by adding   `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:xxx`
  to your gradle or change your minsdk in your gradle to 21 or above (lolipop is the first one to support Material Design).

[Read Documention here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)

to learn more about maintaining backward compatibility.